# Operating a C++ class from Matlab without mex

Tags: c++, matlab

Is there an alternative way to call a `C++` class using `MATLAB`, and operate its methods on `MATLAB` variables?

Comment: You mean no mex files?

Comment: Well `calllib` is the only way I know then.

Comment: C++ has no defacto standard ABI on modern desktop platforms, unlike C. So things are not as simple as "just calling a C++ method".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [calllib](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/calllib.html) to call functions in shared library.

This would be the `newlib.h`

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif
    void *init(int device);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}

#endif
```

and this would be the `newlib.cpp` file

```
#include "newlib.h"
#include "yourlib.h"

A *p;

extern "C" void *init(int device)
{
    p = new A;
    p->yourfunction(device);
}
```

then in `Matlab`

```
clc

LIB_NAME='libnewlib';
INC_NAME='newlib.h';

loadlibrary(LIB_NAME,INC_NAME);

device = 0;

calllib(LIB_NAME,'init', device);

unloadlibrary(LIB_NAME);
```

This has been working fine for me.

Comment: You can, but you still need to provide a plain C wrapper around your C++ classses in order to access their methods.

Comment: Yes, by using the `extern "C"{}`.

Comment: Does that work? Suppose you have a C++ class X with method Foo, can you just put extern "C" around that and build it into a mylib shared library? And then use e.g. `myInstance = callib( 'mylib', 'X::X' ); callib( 'mylib', 'X::Foo', myinstance )`? You should provide more info on how to do that, as the OP asks specifically about C++ classes but the callib documentation only talks about C functions in shared libraries.

Comment: OK, I'll add an example.